Is Cov (X,XY) positive if X,Y >0
if X and Y are random variables which both only take values greater than 0 is their covariance $Cov(X,XY)>0$.
I was able to use the law of total covariance to get to:
$Cov(X,XY)=E[Cov(X,XY|Y)]+Cov(E[X|Y],YE[X|Y])\\
         \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad=E[Y Var(X|Y)]+Cov(E[X|Y],YE[X|Y])$
The first term is clearly +ve but i cannot figure out how to sign the second.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

No. Take $X$ a positive random variable for which $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[1/X]$ both exist, then take $Y = 1/X^2$.
Observe that, by Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}[1/X] \geq 1/\mathbb{E}[X]$, with equality only if $X$ is constant almost surely.
We have
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X,XY) &= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot XY] - \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[XY] \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[1/X]\\
&\leq 1 - 1 \\ &= 0.
\end{align}
So we have $X,Y$ both positive for which $X$ and $XY$ are not positively correlated.

Nice! Taking $X\sim U[a,b]$ with $a>0$ we should be able to show that the covariance is negative.

To give a simple discrete example: let X be equally likely to take the value 1 or 2, and $Y = 1/X^2$ as above.  Then $E(X^2 Y) = E(1) = 1$, $E(X) = 3/2$, $E(XY) = E(1/X) = (1 + 1/2)/2 = 3/4$, $Cov(X, XY) = E(X^2 Y) - E(X) E(XY) = 1 - (3/2)(3/4) = -1/8$.
